# Can't use su or sudo on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, su

Sudo returns this error:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

And su - returns this:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

The user I'm using is a member of the following groups:

```
disk wheel locate network video audio optical floppy storage power users
```

I can log in to root, but can't elevate my user privileges, and I'm sure the password I'm giving to both is correct.

Comment: What is the output of `stat "$(command -v su)" "$(command -v sudo)"`?

Comment: @ChrisDown here it is http://pastebin.com/Rk5y3bMU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason you do not have the the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set on your `su` and `sudo` executables. This bit is required so that `su` and `sudo` can elevate you to run as the root user. You can restore the setuid bit by using `chmod` as root:

```
chmod u+s "$(command -v su)" "$(command -v sudo)"
```

Comment: @MahmoudHossam Note that this may be just the tip of the iceberg. You really should figure out why `su` and `sudo` have the wrong permissions and fix that. There may be other files with wrong permissions or other problems.

Comment: @Gilles I've been using the system for about a week now, nothing seems to be wrong with it for now, but thanks for the suggestion anyway.